# Polling equivalent of AllFramesReady event?

Tags: xna, kinect

I'm using the official Kinect SDK 1.6 with XNA Game Studio 4.0.

I would like to know if anyone has a nice work around to be able to poll for all frames at once, instead of the following:

```
ColorImageFrame cFrame = _Device.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(100);
DepthImageFrame dFrame = _Device.DepthStream.OpenNextFrame(100);
SkeletonFrame sFrame = _Device.SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame(100);
```

I would rather not make three synchronous calls in my loop. I was really hoping for something like `_Device.OpenAllFrames(100)` but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of the AllFramesReady event for the polling method.

I cannot switch to the event driven method as it doesn't really suite XNA. Or does anyone have a better method to access Kinect's streams inside XNA's loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making your own simple Kinect manager on top of the SDK (it's what I did in one of my projects).

This manager could be a singleton object that listens for events from the depth, color and skeleton streams and just saves the latest available frames to some local variables (you could also optimize and disable some streams if they are not needed)

In your XNA game loop you can then access these variables and you will have the latest frames available. Some thread synchronization will be needed to prevent reading the variables while the manager is writing to them.

In addition to this feature, this manager also helped me handle the case where the Kinect sensor disconnects/reconnects. Instead of always testing if a sensor is connected, the manager object is always there but it will simply not have any new frames stored locally.

Of course, the XNA game can still handle the disconnect/connect event in case it wants to do something special, but in the game loop I don't have to always test if there is a valid kinect sensor attached.